# Create php file with content from terminal

Tags: php, frameworks, terminal

I was wondering how, for example, cakePHP can use the terminal/command line to create files and put content in it. I guess they use some kind of template for the content but how do they do it?

I know that you can create controllers and so on with it. Anyone know how it's done?

/ Tobias

EDIT: I've been searching and searching but can't find anything about this. Please is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Dunno about the file part, but you can run php content striaght from the terminal using something like the following: 
`php -r 'echo "shit!";'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates for easy to create files or something like [Zend_CodeGenerator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html) for a more elaborate approach. Apart from that, have a look at the sourcecode for [CakePHP's `bake`](http://api.cakephp.org/file/cake/console/libs/bake.php) if you are specifically interested in how they do it.

Comment: I've been looking at it but I don't really get it, never worked with it before. Is there any tutorials or something out there I can take a look at?

Comment: Well, there is examples for Zend_CodeGenerator on the page I linked. And for Cake, I am sure they have examples on their pages somewhere.